# Union types : Property does not exist on type object

Tags: typescript, union-types

Object type is not recognized on an interface property with multiple types.
In my case, `answer` property with `PostalAnswer` type.

```js
interface Question {
    id: number;
    answer: string | string[] | PostalAnswer;
}
interface PostalAnswer { address: string; city: string; code: string; }

const formQuestions: Question[] = [
    {
        id: 0,
        answer: 'Bonjour'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        answer: { address: '1 rue', city: 'Paris', code: '75001' }
    }
];

console.log(formQuestions[1].answer.address);
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=46&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcIGczAPYjIDeAUMucsACYBcyI6AtgEbQDcZFcIWA7tHRxRQAc2QAfZENEBtALoTkABTw44AGwCCPflA4BfEqEixEKFWq07oxZHCpUo2LILDCQItsgTAwAT1d3T288KghA0S9DEgQCHGQYPChGDGxcOLpUnHwQeWQAXmQZTnJSCnLKWmQABgAaEoruPgFkAHIAIQIAKzx0KFaG-XrysoryajoARmGxu2soOiI7BycsFzbJ5ChMVtrvXwC2pThhLF2QsLpWgHYAVmrqydbkQ3LDOQ4YuLx1CAA6dR4EQACkSySy6R4Mkmcj+TV0cJWzgAlGwgA)

I get this error on the last line:

> Property 'address' does not exist on type 'string | PostalAnswer | string[]'.
>      Property 'address' does not exist on type 'string'. ts(2339)

**Note:** If `answer` property has only one type `PostalAnswer`, there is no error anymore.

Comment: If you post a complete example that displays your type error on a [typescript playground] you're likely to get more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
interface Question {
    id: number;
    answer: string | string[] | PostalAnswer;
}
interface PostalAnswer { address: string; city: string; code: string; }

const formQuestions: Question[] = [
    {
        id: 0,
        answer: 'Bonjour'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        answer: { address: '1 rue', city: 'Paris', code: '75001' }
    }
];

const question = formQuestions[1];
if (typeof question.answer === "object" && !Array.isArray(question.answer)) { // Typeguard
    console.log(question.answer.address);
}
```

You can also make a function:

```
console.log(isPostalAnswer(formQuestions[1].answer) && formQuestions[1].answer.address);

function isPostalAnswer(potentialAnswer: any): potentialAnswer is PostalAnswer {
    return typeof potentialAnswer === "object"
        && "address" in potentialAnswer
        && "city" in potentialAnswer
        && "code" in potentialAnswer;
}
```